Learning rate for Autoencoder

if I set lower bound to zero , it look like linear other wise it look little better, is this good/high/low learning rate ?
Autoencoder , batch size 16 , learning rate : 3 e-5 , and loss function root mean square error
Training sample : 20982 , validation samples : 5246

I don't think there's an answer. If you tested multiple learning rates and plotted the corresponding loss curves, it could've been possible to say the best learning rate (for your particular data, model and loss function) is the one whose loss curve is steepest. Here you have only one specimen, so I don't think it's possible to tell if it's a "good" or "bad" learning rate.
